# JQuery Autocomplete not working within current code

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I am using autocomplete with mysql to look up possible matches from a database...

It works if I empty the page out completely... but doesn't work once I add my page content...

I am getting no errors in the console either..

This is where I add the JS libraries

```
 <script src="templates/bower_components/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="templates/bower_components/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="templates/bower_components/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="templates/bower_components/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script src="templates/bower_components/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script src="templates/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
```

and this is my autocomplete function...

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#tags").autocomplete({

          source: "templates/search2.php?field=sire",
          minLength: 5 

      });

  });
</script>
```

And this is my text box

```
<input type="text" class="input tiny search-term" name="proposeddam"  id = "tags">
```

I have added an alert box within the function but it never seems to be called..

Any suggestions?

Comment: where did u put alert?

Comment: try like this http://easyautocomplete.com/

Comment: I added the alert after the $(document).ready.. line